# Angularjs UI-Router workflow for async data

Tags: json, angularjs, asynchronous, angular-ui-router

I have a rather simple Angular App for a product cataloque, pulling one big JSON file from a CMS. The JSON holds info needed in several parts of the app (menu, pagination, product list, product details), so several controllers need access to it.
They way I did it is to define

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart',
    function(evt, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){  
        loader.getData(toParams);
    });
```

in `app.run();`. The `loader` factory then `$broadcast`s the data to all the controllers. This works fine, but the application "blinks" on every state change, since UI-Router starts the controller / loads the template without data while waiting for the async data.
I guess the correct way of doing this is to use `resolve` in `$stateProvider.state()` but I can't figure out how to $inject my loader into config or make my data availabe to all the other controllers.
Is there a way to make resolve wait for a broadcast? Or is there another approach?
This is my first angular project so please excuse if this is easy / obvious or stupid.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone running into the same problem: Dependencies don't need to be injected into config, they go into resolve, which takes everything. So my code looks like this now:

```
`.state('produkte.list',{
    url:':main/:sub/?p=:page&o=:order&f=:filter&b=:brand',
    resolve : {
      data:['$stateParams','loader',function($stateParams,loader) {
        return loader.getData($stateParams);
      }]
    },  
    [...]`
```

The loader still broadcasts it's results to any controller interested so it's all good (meaning, it works)